# Task :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForLive

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

> Task :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForLive FAILED
>   Error in /app/multidex-config.pro:
>     Failed to read file: /app/multidex-config.pro

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForLive'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s
51 actionable tasks: 26 executed, 25 up-to-date

Comment: Any one please help me to fix this issue ...

Comment: I'm getting the same issue since the build tools were updated. Could be related to the new D8 compiler step.

Comment: OK, in my case I solved it by running the command gradlew [module name]:dependencies and realizing that there was I dependency for which gradle was not able to recursively update the support libraries.

There seem to be other people on the web with similar issues because they still include JAR files manually. 

Hope this can help anyone :)

Comment: I tried that gradle command not working

Comment: You have to be on the project root to run that command, its part of the project. Also, be sure to replace [module name] with your own module name. (Usually called `app`  by default if I'm not mistaken)